# Creating a matrix from a function handle (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, function, matrix, handle

What I intend to do is very simple but yet I haven't found a proper way to do it. I have a function handle which depends on two variables, for example:

```
f = @(i,j) i+j
```

(mine is quite more complicated, though)

What I'd like to do is to create a matrix M such that

```
M(i,j) = f(i,j)
```

Of course I could use a nested loop but I'm trying to avoid those. I've already managed to do this in Maple in a quite simple way:

```
f:=(i,j)->i+j;
M:=Matrix(N,f);
```

(Where N is the dimension of the matrix) But I need to use MATLAB for this. For now I'm sticking to the nested loops but I'd really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
>> [ii jj] = ndgrid(1:4 ,1:5); %// change i and j limits as needed
>> M = bsxfun(f, ii, jj)

M =

     2     3     4     5     6
     3     4     5     6     7
     4     5     6     7     8
     5     6     7     8     9
```

If your function `f` satisfies the following condition:

> `C = fun(A,B)` accepts arrays `A` and `B` of **arbitrary, but equal size** and returns output of the same size. Each element in the output array `C` is the result of an operation on the corresponding elements of `A` and `B` only. `fun` must also support **scalar expansion**, such that if `A` or `B` is a scalar, `C` is the result of applying the scalar to every element in the other input array.

you can dispose of `ndgrid`. Just add a transpose (`.'`) to the first (`i`) vector:

```
>> M = bsxfun(f, (1:4).', 1:5)
```

Comment: I wonder if `@plus` might be more efficient if `f` is nothing more than `@(i,j)i+j`?

Comment: @horchler For that specific case, I guess so. And `ndgrid` could also be disposed of

Comment: Thank you very much @LuisMendo ! Your answer was trully helpful.

Comment: @JavierGarcia Glad about that! You work in Quamtum Mechanivs, wow!

Answer (score 0):

*Function handles* can accept matrices as inputs.  Simply pass a square matrix of size `N` where the values corresponds to the row number for `i`, and a square matrix of size `N` where the values correspond to the column number for `j`.

```
N = 5;
f = @(i,j) i+j;
M = f(meshgrid(1:N+1), meshgrid(1:N+1)')
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.